# Does the main window only update after a slot subroutine returns?

Tags: qt

I don't know if I can explain this problem without posting reams of code, but here goes.

I have a Qt app which is supposed to display a sequence of images. Each image is displayed in the main Qt window by using a QLabel. To display each image, I wrote a subrotuine called DisplayImg(int i) where the integer i is the frame number. It works for displaying single images.

I then created a 'Play' button (in Qt) which is supposed to play a sequence of images. The Play button is connected to a slot which is named on_Play_clicked(). That is a subroutine which does this:

```
for (i = 0 ; i < N ; i++) 
    DisplayImg(i);
```

The problem is that the display only changes for the final image in the sequence. None of the intermediate images are displayed, even though I know (from printf()) that DisplayImg() is called for all intermediate images.

Is that enough information to explain the problem? Am I misunderstanding how the slot works?  Does the main Qt window not update until the subroutine on_Play_clicked() returns?

Comment: I changed all QT to Qt since QT more often refers to Apple QuickTime and not Nokia's Qt framework.

Answer (score 3):

Yes. Qt performs painting only when the control flow is back in the event loop. You should create a `QTimer`, connect its `timeout` signal to a slot and start the timer with desired interval in milliseconds. In the slot you should display the next image, e.g. `DisplayImg(i); i++;`. Current image number (i) should be stored in a class member variable. When the last image is displayed, stop the timer.

Comment: +1. Doing this any other way will lock the UI anyway, which would drive any user up the wall.

Answer (score 0):

The reason that your images don't appear to be changing on the Qt main window is that you don't have a delay between changing each of your images. If you change your code to something like this, you should get the desired effect:

```
for (i = 0 ; i < N ; i++)   
    QTimer::singleShot(5000 * i, this, SLOT(DisplayImg(i))); // sleep 5 seconds and then call display image
```

You will need to declare your DisplayImage method as a slot in your class like so:
yourclass.h

```
#include <QtCore>

class YourClass : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
private slots:
    void DisplayImage(int i);

// private members
// public members

};
```

Comment: You're setting all singleshots in the one moment with the same interval, so the slot will be called many times without delay. It should be like `singleShot(5000 * i, ...)`.

Comment: Actually, I did have a sleep(1) delay in the loop.  I don't know what singleShot() is.

Comment: @JB_User `QTimer::singleShot()` sets a timer once and executes a slot at the end of the time interval. If you are unfamiliar with slots and signals, you should read about them here: http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtcore/signalsandslots.html

Comment: Sleep is not welcome in Qt. You should not use it in most cases.

Answer (score 0):

Just for completeness. Often for a problem like this QCoreApplication::processEvents() is a solution.
So your code would look like:

```
for (i = 0 ; i < N ; i++) {
    QCoreApplication::processEvents();
    DisplayImg(i);
}
```

BUT... The timer solution is clearly superior to the processEvent solution in this particular case. You just have more control over your display.